# How to prevent get request from being send if the length of the query field is short in react-admin

Tags: react-admin

I'm using react-admin and trying to create a filter with autocomplete field that will make a query as I type and will only start sending the query when the search criteria length is longer then 2.

I'm currently using `shouldRenderSuggestions` inside of my `AutocompleteInput` field but this still send two requests with an empty string in the "nickname" filter, this is the code part:

```
<AutocompleteInput optionText="nickname" shouldRenderSuggestions={(val) => {
        return val.trim().length > 2
      }}/>
```

The thing that happens is when I fill in the first and second letters the `GET` request is sent but with an empty string in the `nickname` field,

The string input is for example:"abc":

1ST request:
`http://website.loc/clients?filter={"nickname":""}&page=1&perPage=25&range=[0,24]&sort=["id","DESC"]`

2ND request:
`http://website.loc/clients?filter={"nickname":""}&page=1&perPage=25&range=[0,24]&sort=["id","DESC"]`

3RD request:
`http://website.loc/clients?filter={"nickname":"abc"}&page=1&perPage=25&range=[0,24]&sort=["id","DESC"]`

I want to avoid from sending the first two requests entirely.

The full code of the component:

```
const PostPagination = props => (
  <Pagination rowsPerPageOptions={[]} {...props} />
);

const PostFilter = (props) => (
  <Filter {...props}>
    <ReferenceInput label="Client"
                    source="client_id"
                    reference="clients"
                    allowEmpty
                    filterToQuery={searchText => ({ nickname: searchText })}>
      <AutocompleteInput optionText="nickname" shouldRenderSuggestions={(val) => {
        return val.trim().length > 2
      }}/>
    </ReferenceInput>
  </Filter>
);

const PostsList = props => {
  return (
    <List {...props} perPage={15}
          pagination={<PostPagination/>}
          filters={<PostFilter/>}
          exporter={false}>
      <Datagrid>
        <TextField source="nickname" sortable={false}/>
        <DateField label="Created" source="created_at" showTime/>
      </Datagrid>
    </List>
  );
};
```

**Edit:** same question goes for "search-as-you-type" fields like `<TextInput>` inside a <`Filter>` field, I started to ask a new question but realized it will be kind of a duplicate,

This is the code that also sends requests starting from 1 char, in this case there isn't even a `shouldRenderSuggestions` option to force it to send empty requests

```
const ClientFilter = (props) => (
  <Filter {...props}>
    <TextInput label="Search" source="str" alwaysOn/>
  </Filter>
);
```

[Live example of code in codesandbox.io](https://k2r9p6r18r.codesandbox.io/#/posts/create)

Comment: It shouldn't make that many requests. What version of react-admin are you using? Can you set up a codesandbox showcasing the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled upon this issue, too. The best I've come up with so far is a small wrapper component that prevents the `ReferenceInput` from triggering API requests unless a certain condition is met:

```js
  const ConditionalFilter = (props) => {
    const { children, condition, setFilter } = props;
    const conditionalSetFilter = (val) => {
      if (setFilter && condition(val)) setFilter(val);
    };
    return React.cloneElement(children, { ...props, setFilter: conditionalSetFilter });
  };
```

Used like this:

```js
  const condition = val => val.trim().length > 2;
  return (
    <ReferenceInput 
      source="…"
      reference="…"
      shouldRenderSuggestions={condition}
    >
      <ConditionalFilter condition={condition}>
        <AutocompleteInput />
      </ConditionalFilter>
    </ReferenceInput>
  );
```

**Update for react-admin v3:** (without the wrapper component, which is no longer necessary/useful)

```js
const condition = (val) => !!val && val.trim().length > 2;
return (
  <ReferenceInput
    source="…"
    reference="…"
    filterToQuery={(val) => (condition(val) ? { name: val.trim() } : {})}
  >
    <AutocompleteInput shouldRenderSuggestions={condition} />
  </ReferenceInput>
);
```

Comment: I was hoping to get an official answer by Gildas Garcia but your answer did the trick, Thanks.