# React-Admin: Disable "Search-as-you-type" for Fitler

Tags: react-admin

I was searching for a way to disable "search-as-you-type" for Filter in React-Admin.

Found this related question "[How to prevent get request from being send if the length of the query field is short in react-admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55099475/how-to-prevent-get-request-from-being-send-if-the-length-of-the-query-field-is-s/55340065#55340065)" but it has no answers...

Does anybody knows how to do this?

Tried to find something at the source codes but without success:

- https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/0e6605948439f94681d027c4106b627ca9a5a15b/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/list/Filter.js
- https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/8f0922f913d58709617c12b952fe2a618ffcb8a8/packages/ra-core/src/actions/filterActions.ts
- https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/432d7a26bbfe9424729a9da039a010ec00f2bcca/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/list/FilterForm.js

Comment: react admin uses global filter for search-as-you-type means its for instant search.https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/docs/Tutorial.md#adding-search-and-filters-to-the-list.
i think its a must feature they have to add to reduce request life cycle.